# Store files temporarily on server until a task is completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I cant use sessions.

So heres the scenario: I want the user to upload an image, but that image needs to be a particular size. So I allow them to upload any size image, store that temporarily on the server (resize it so it fits on the webpage), display it back to the user, let the user crop it. I then send the crop details back to the server, crop the image and save it and use it as the users profile picture.

I tried to do all this before uploading, but apparently, its a security risk and not allowed.

So how do I temporarily store this file? What if the user does not come back before cropping, I dont want a large image like that sitting on my server. How would I go about removing the file in a stateless application like this?

Files are stored on a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve this, but perhaps an easy way is that every time a file is uploaded, call a little routine that checks for, and deletes, any 'large' files that are over xxx minutes old.

Alternatively, schedule a job to do the same every xxx minutes in the task scheduler.

Comment: I have no idea what a task scheduler is. Is this in asp.net or is it iis?

Comment: Its in windows, you would need access to the machine to do this, i.e. physically or thru RDP. If you are hosting this on a shared account at your ISP it wouldn't be an option most likely, so then go with option A - have each file upload process do a little housecleaning as part of servicing the request, i.e. getting rid of orphaned files.

Comment: Quartz.NET is an example of a task/job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TempData](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications), which is similar to Session, but dies after being read.

Comment: This would require the image to be uploaded again?